# saturation of negative values in gdal_calc.py when subtracting L8 bands

Tags: python, gdal, subtraction

I am trying to subtract two bands of Landsat8 with `gdal_calc.py` as following:

```
gdal_calc.py -A LC8_B4.TIF -B LC8_B5.TIF --outfile="$pathout"/B5minusB4.tif --type='Int16' --calc="B-A"
```

It is clear that the output is a signed number (i.e. `Int16`), however I never get negative values, when a value is supposed to be negative after the subtraction I get the value 32767. Is there a way to fix this in the `--calc` expression? This is the first step in calculating the NDVI for L8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using the `astype()` method of `numpy.ndarray`, which is the datatype represented by `A` and `B` in the `calc` expression.

`--calc="B.astype(int16) - A.astype(int16)"`

These `int16` are actually `numpy.int16` but the calculation expression takes place within the `numpy` namespace.

```
gdal_calc.py -A LC8_B4.TIF -B LC8_B5.TIF \
  --outfile="$pathout"/B5minusB4.tif --type='Int16' \ 
  --calc="B.astype(int16) - A.astype(int16)"
```

What's even better is if you set the NoDataValue for the input rasters beforehand. This will ensure the calculated-zero NDVI values within the good part of the raster aren't flagged as NoData because they have the same value as the `0 - 0` "NDVI" from the NoData space.

```
gdal_edit.py -a_nodata 0 LC8_B4.TIF 
gdal_edit.py -a_nodata 0 LC8_B5.TIF 
# gdal_calc.py ...
```

Comment: That works! I ended up with one single line for calculation NDVI:    gdal_calc.py -A LC8_B4.TIF -B LC8_B5.TIF \ --outfile="$pathout"/ndvi_stackoverflow_oneoff.tif --type='Float32' \
  --calc="(B.astype(float32) - A.astype(float32)) / (B.astype(float32) + A.astype(float32))"